# OSX Quick Look generator: How to have animated thumbnail icons?

Tags: xcode, macos, quicklook

For quicktime and other video files, apples quicklook thumbnails are able to preview the video. How could I implement something when building my own generator that could either play the video or show a slideshow of images?

Comment: I also noticed a similar enhancement in icons for PDF files: they have left and right arrows, and so you can browse them!